# Can I add and reference a private email address to my profile for others to see?

Tags: support, profile-page

I see that web sites, Twitter accounts, and LinkedIn accounts can be added to a profile. In another section, can I add a reference to an email account on Gmail?

I am having a lively discussion in a Stack Exchange group, and I am wondering if it could be continued privately if I put out a general invite to everyone in a comment?

Answer (score 14):

**Yes,** you can include an email address in your profile if you wish (see mine for an example).

**But no,** you may ***not*** ask users to contact you privately in an answer or a comment (to "continue the conversation" or otherwise). Everything we do on this site is for the public benefit, so you can imagine the major issues we'd have with "contact me offline for help" and the spam/solicitations if we allowed folks to steer contacts offline. We do not allow solicitations for personal contact in the main Q&A. If you see them, they **should be 'flagged'** for immediate removal.

But leaving an email address in your profile is perfectly appropriate.